# Is there any way to close meet from jitsy meet wrapper?

Tags: flutter, dart

I wonder, can i somehow programically close the meet incoming via jitsi meet wrapper?

I checked the documentation of package but no word about it. There is no available function as I see. So I wonder, any possible way for it?

Thank u in advance

Answer (score 0):

NO.
Jitsi Meet plugin has JitsiMeet.closeMeeting();
They have not included this in Jitsi Meet Wrapper plugin.